# Create Pivot Table Or Groupby with a Column Thais is a List in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can i create a pivot table or groupby where column List2 is a index as df below.

```
col Order             List2
1   4.049765e+10    [WGMG37594]
2   4.049918e+10    [GRHA04251]
3   4.050495e+10    [VLEY32568]
4   4.050695e+10    [WAOB15065]
5   4.050744e+10    [TGSX00082]
... ... ...
8574    4.053194e+10    [ETNV38669]
8575    4.053194e+10    [GBGN09839]
8576    4.053196e+10    [FLFH04515]
8577    4.053196e+10    [EYIZ13249]
8578    4.053196e+10    [VSPW58069]
```

I using code below.

```
df3 = df3.groupby('List2').count().reset_index()
```

However it returns the error below, same happens with pivot table.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

There are any alternative for that?

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: Convert them to tuples (if you have multiple elements in array)  before grouping, else grab the first entry `.str[0]` and group